# Cannot use python to connect with hive database through thrift

Tags: python, hive

log is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 3, in 
conn = hive.Connection(host = '192.168.85.200', port = 10000, username = 'hive', database = 'default')
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 192, in **init**
self._transport.open()
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line 93, in open
status, payload = self._recv_sasl_message()
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line 112, in _recv_sasl_message
header = self._trans_read_all(5)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line 198, in _trans_read_all
return read_all(sz)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 62, in readAll
chunk = self.read(sz - have)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 143, in read
message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes

```
`
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host = '192.168.85.200', port = 10000, username = 'hive', database = 'default')
#host主机ip,port：端口号，username:用户名，database:使用的数据库名称
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
# 打印结果
for result in cursor.fetchall():
     print(result)
`
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.